# Hide/disable some node in the treeview according to some conditions

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, treeview

I have three levels (one , two, three) represented as a radiobuttonlist. Also, I have treeview represents these levels (each level represented as a parent node and each level has a child) 
My goal is:  If the user check on level one in the radibutonlist, the treeview will hide or disable level two and three. if the user check on level two in the radio button list, the treeview will hide or disable level three.

I did not find code to hide or disable nodes in treeview based on conditions. could you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

You have to be more specific. Where do you want to do that? On server side with C#, in client side with your own javascript or in client side using jquery?

Doing that on server side with c# you can use the RadioButtonList.SelectedIndexChanged event to rebuild the tree in any way you want, supposing the tree you refer is TreeView from ASP.NET.
You can add/remove TreeNodes to the TreeView or you can set, for each TreeNode, the SelectAction event you want (Expand, None, Select, SelectExpand).

Comment: I want to do it in the client side